# Tracking push notifications that I receive on my android phone

Tags: applications, sms, push-notifications

I'm trying to set up a tracker that stores text messages and push notification that I receive on my phone in a google sheets spreadsheet. I have already found a way to forward each SMS that I receive to a spreadsheet using [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/). Unfortunately, it seems that IFTTT does not allow you to track push notifications as well.

**Question:** (If it's possible) How do I set up tracking push notifications on an android phone?

Comment: everything is in a sqlite database somewhere, just find the file and export content? not sure maybe it is included in notifications? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree

Comment: @alecxs thanks for the tip! I might actually do that, but I was hoping to build a more automated process, so that whenever I receive a push notification it gets forwarded to another location

Answer (score 1):

Google push notifications are handled differently than SMS. AFAIK only Google Play Services app has access to all push notifications (as it receives them). Therefore getting those push notifications would require to inject code into Google Play Services, e.g. in form of an XPosed module (requires rooted device + (ed)Xposed installed).

BTW: The push notification often does not contain the actual data. It can be used to "poke" an app so that the app connects to it's backend and loads the actual data (e.g. a messenger message).

Comment: Thank you Robert for your reply! How much time would it take to write such code? Isn't there a service that does this? All I want is to track push notifications that I receive from sports websites, and delivery apps.

Comment: @titusAdam That depends on how familiar you are with app development, XPosed module development and reverse engineering of Android apps. However there is one problem: the Google Play Services app is a "moving target" it is frequently updated and if it obfuscates it's class names (have not checked it) most likely you would have to adapt the Xposed module after every update.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't accepted your answer yet. Do you think that this is an option? https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/send-notifications?code-sample=code-receiving-a-notification-in-android-1&code-language=Android%20-%20Java&code-sdk-version=default

Comment: @titusAdam This article describes how to receive any push notification sent to the app that is being developed in the article, not to all apps system wide.

Comment: so this will only work for push notifications that are received on your own app? :)